# Create hash_hmac sha512 passowrds from array using PHP

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I need to run some old passwords through hash_hmac.

```
$password = array ('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');

foreach (hash_hmac() as $v) {
    $r = hash_hmac($v, $password, false);
    echo "$v";
}
```

I get a "hash_hmac expects a string. I may be way off on this but it seems simple in my head.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `foreach ($password as $v) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your passing the wrong arguments to the hash_hmac function. First argument is the algorithm, second is the data, third is a shared key.

```
foreach ($password as $v) {
$r = hash_hmac('sha512', $v, 'key');
echo $r;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can learn more about `hash_hmac` on [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)

```
$password = array ('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');

    foreach ($password as $v) {
        $r[] = hash_hmac('sha512', $v, 'key');
    }
    print_r($r);
```